# Security Deposits with Stripe Longer than 7 Days

Tags: stripe-payments

How does one do a security deposit—longer than 7 days—style hold using Stripe with cards payments?

According to Stripe's documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method), holds last for up to 7 days.  But, if you're in a hotel-like scenario where the customer is using the service for longer than 7 days, how are holds managed using stripe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe supports extended authorizations for card present transaction via their Terminal product ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/features/extended-authorizations)). This allows you to hold funds for longer than 7 days. This should fit the hotel scenario you outlined.

It's not publicly supported for card not present transactions (online transactions) for now. If you need this, it is likely worth discussing this with their [support team](https://support.stripe.com/contact).